How do properly position my widgets relative to each other and the center of the window with tkinter?
So I am having trouble creating a GUI that can dynamically adjust to the size of my window. What's going on is that one, I want my widgets to scale automatically with the width of my window. I also want it so stop scaling when it gets to big, or too small. Number 2 is I want to know how I can position each of my widgets to have a location relative to the size of the screen so it can quickly adjust to different window sizes. What I mean by this is I want to have each widget be in the same location relative to a certain point or sets of points on the window. Like for example there will be a point at the center of the screen and the widget will generally stay there, or the corner, side, etc. I was also wondering if I could also position widgets relative to each other as well.
I would appreciate any of the knowledge above what I'm trying to do is to center the widgets on my window of my code shown below. Right now it's on the top and I want to put it at the center. I also want to have the home_label be positioned relative to the home_combobox.
from tkinter import *
import ttkbootstrap as tb

root = tb.Window(themename='superhero')

#root
root.title('Learn Vocab')
#add icon here root.iconbitmap()
root.geometry('500x550')

# create home frame
home_frame = tb.Frame(root)
home_frame.pack(anchor=CENTER)

# create home label
home_label = tb.Label(home_frame, text='Main Menu', font=('Helvetica', 36))
home_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=50)

# create combobox
home_combobox = tb.Combobox(home_frame, values=['placeholder 1', 'placeholder 2'])
home_combobox.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()


I tried looking online but I couldn't understand anything as I am a new coder. I was wondering if anyone could solve my issue and preferably point me to a couple of videos I could watch.

Thanks for making me work for this. Your question is important because, with this we can avoid finding out the height and width of the root by trial and error.
from tkinter import *
import ttkbootstrap as tb

root = tb.Window(themename='superhero')

#root
root.title('Learn Vocab')
# create home frame
home_frame = tb.Frame(root)
home_frame.pack(anchor=CENTER)

# padx and pady values of each widget
pad_x, pad_y = 10, 20

# create home label
home_label = tb.Label(home_frame, text='Main Menu', font=('Helvetica', 36))

# pack using pack method
home_label.pack(side='top', pady=pad_y, padx=pad_x)

# create combobox
home_combobox = tb.Combobox(home_frame, values=['placeholder 1', 'placeholder 2'])

# pack using pack method
home_combobox.pack(side='top', pady=pad_y, padx=pad_x)

# Create a list of widgets    
wdgt_lst = [home_label, home_combobox]
 
# This line is important only then we  would be able to get height and width of the widgets
# The purpose is : with update_idle_tasks() widgets don't wait till root.mainloop()
root.update_idletasks()


# The following calculation is done to calculate the total height of the widgets and width of widget with max width
hght = 0
width_ls = []
for x in wdgt_lst:
    
    x.pack(side = 'top', pady = pad_y, padx = pad_x)
    widget_height = x.winfo_height()
    widget_width = x.winfo_width()
    width_ls.append(widget_width)
    
    hght = hght + pad_y*2 + widget_height
    
root_width = max(width_ls) + 2*pad_x + 2*pad_x
root_height = hght + 2*pad_y

# Declare root_width and root_height from the calculated value
root.geometry(f'{root_width}x{root_height}')

root.mainloop()

Edit
To Scale the widget according to the root_window's size:
root_height =  root.winfo_height()
root_width = root.winfo_width()

def scale_widget():
    new_root_height =  root.winfo_height()
    root_width = root.winfo_width()
    for x in wdgt_lst:
        current_widget_height = x.winfo_height()
        new_height = (current_widget_height/root_height)*new_root_height
        new_width = (current_widget_width/root_width)*new_root_width
        x.pack_forget()
        x.configure(width = new_width, height = new_height)
        x.pack()

# window resizing event is called <Configure> event. Bind this with the function we created
root.bind('<Configure>', scale_widget)

I'm sorry. I typed directly in the answer box and couldn't check for it's working now(Only edited portion).

Thanks, I want to mark this as an answer however, I still need to know how to shrink or scale my widgets to the width of the window.

@RichmondNguyen, I've edited my answer. After my previous code, I've added another function to do this. Please check.

To put the widgets in the center of the window, you can simply add expand=True to home_frame.pack(...), then home_frame will be put at the center of the space allocated for it, i.e the window for your case because it is the only child of the window:
home_frame.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=True)

